# How can i send my current location (longitude & latitude) with a standard text (I'm here) with an email when i hit a button?

Tags: email, windows-phone-7, latitude-longitude

I want to know how can i send an email with a standard text like "Hello, i'm here" with my current location (longitude & latitude) when i just hit a button in a windows phone 7.5 application.

The steps are:

1) Hit the button
2) An email (from my account) automatically send it to another standard email with
my current longitude & latitude, name of the City and a standard text "Hello, i'm here".

Thanks in advance

---

It works perfectly. Thanks MyKuLLSKI.

But i have a "problem". I don't want to open the email application. I want to skip that. When the user push the button, i want to send the email with the current location instantly and without the user do something else (more clicks).

One click = email send with location and text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Thos I hope this is exactly what you are looking for. I do not have my device on hand but this should work.

#### References Needed

```
System.Device
```

#### WMAppManifest (Add this to the Capabilities child)

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
```

#### XAML

```
<Button Click="ButtonClick"/>
```

#### Code Behind

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher _GeoCoordinateWatcher;
private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _GeoCoordinateWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
        _GeoCoordinateWatcher.MovementThreshold = 10; // 10 meters. 
        _GeoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(GeoCoordinateWatcherPositionChanged);
        _GeoCoordinateWatcher.Start();
    }

    catch
    {
    }
}

private void GeoCoordinateWatcherPositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
{
    _GeoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged -= GeoCoordinateWatcherPositionChanged;

    string latitude = e.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString("0.0000");
    string longitude = e.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString("0.0000");
    string altitude = e.Position.Location.Altitude.ToString("0.0000");

    _GeoCoordinateWatcher.Stop();
    _GeoCoordinateWatcher.Dispose();
    _GeoCoordinateWatcher = null;

    SendEmail("ToAddress@EmailClient.com", "Location", string.Concat("Hello, I'm here: ", latitude, " ", longitude, " ", altitude);
}

private void SendEmail(string to, string subject, string message)
{
    EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
    emailcomposer.To = to;
    emailcomposer.Subject = subject;
    emailcomposer.Body = message;
    emailcomposer.Show();
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks MyKuLLSKI.

But i have a "problem". I don't want to open the email application. I want to skip that. When the user push the button, i want to send the email with the current location instantly and without the user do something else (more clicks).

One click = email send with location and text

Comment: Sorry you cannot do that easily. You have to create your own webservice that the user must subscribe to. Basically you have a service the phone signs up for and your service on a real pc sends the email....So if your trying to build a "Find My Phone" app then you'll need your own server that sends email based on the credentials people provide to you.

Comment: But i don't want to send email from my pc but from my mobile app at a specific email address. Now the code is working perfectly, but i want to skip the steps, opening email application, write something and then push again to send. i just want with one click to send the email with locations at a specific email address.

Comment: You cant @Thor. WP7 DOES NOT allow you to do that. Every email app out there sends the email from a server

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry that Microsoft restricted you. Please return the favor and mark this as the answer.